# UnicodedecoderError;'ascii' codec cant' decode when querying data on hive with python

Tags: python, sql, hive, odbc

I'm trying to pass variables to query for hive database but I have run into unicodedecoderError as below.

Below is my codes.

```
 import pyodbc
 import pandas as pd

 var1 = 'UCSB'
 my_connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MapR-64-Hive', autocommit=True)
 my_cursor = my_connection.cursor()
 my_query =  """
     select *  from polaris_datasets.snmaster  where parent_pid rlike ‘%s’  and created_date >=  "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
     """ 

 my_cursor.execute(my_query,  var1)
```

and the Error is as below.

```
 >>> my_cursor.execute(my_query, var1)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 70: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm not sure if this is syntax issue or encoding issue so I need to change somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The second apostrophe used as a single quote around %s is not an ASCII character. Replace the single quote characters with '':

```
my_query =  """
 select *  from polaris_datasets.snmaster  where parent_pid rlike '%s'  and 
created_date >=  "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
 """
```

Comment: thanks, with this change, it solves unidecodeError. but I have run into another issue as below. >>> my_cursor.execute(my_query, var1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')